# What is the meaning of Feet Floating

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was reading English news paper & I came across one word Feet Floating, What does it mean?

I googled but I didn't understand

[image]

Comment: Read the two words separately, it's not a phrase: "... with turned feet", "floating over". - HTH.

Comment: The question is based on incorrect parsing.

Comment: oh! Thank you for correcting me. Than what does it mean Floating Over?

Comment: Try insert "that is" between "feet" and "floating" that might help you understand.  Also, floating means to be suspended in air in this case, floating over would mean suspended above a parapet. You could also think of floating over a parapet as "hovering over a parapet".

Comment: @Zebrafish- Now somewhat clear. Floating over parapet mean touching to parapet or there is space b/w parapet & feet? or it mean walking on parapet?

Comment: @Arvindraja  Whether it's floating along the parapet, ie., moving along the edge of the parapet, I think the previous sentence tells us that he is quite still, when it says "He just sits by the broken parapet and hums an old song." Also, having said that, the same sentence might suggest that he is floating above the parapet and touching it, as he is sitting. Generally floating above something means to hover above it without touching, but in this case maybe not, given that it says that "he sits by the broken parapet".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading correction to be done:

Sure, an apparition with turned feet, floating over a parapet and humming may be an unusual sight, but completely harmless.

Comment: If you don't mind, Could you please tell meaning of humming & unusual sight.  I mean meaning of this line `humming may be an unusual sight`

Comment: @Arvindraja - Do you understand the meaning of "apparition"?  This is a "ghost" or "spirit", and it is apt to do strange & mystical things.  (Please consult a dictionary.)

Comment: The meaning in this context describes a ghost humming a tune, which is considered to occur not very often.

It simply means to say that the scene of a ghost/apparition humming is not a normal occurrence.

Comment: Thnk you. Actually I am want to ask you, Humming means song or tune, than how someone(ghost) can hum an unusual sight(scene). I want to say ghost can hum an unusual song(not sight). Hope you understand

Comment: An apparition ... may be an unusual sight.  The rest describes the apparition.  The apparition is humming.  We are not told what it is humming.  In particular, this does not mean it is humming an unusual sight.

Comment: @GEdgar- Now it is clear enough. 